# how to configure node app and haProxy in docker container?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, haproxy

I trying to configure my node app (will scale) and haProxy docker container in ubuntu VM.
i don't understand how it work? how i have to configure docker-compose file ho make it work properly.
My node app work at 8080 port and i can see one in my browser (with port binding from VM(guest:80 to host:8080), or open VM ip in chrome), but i dont expose him(port 8080) in dockerfile or docker-compose. should it be so?

since apps work on 8080 port, i have to bind him to another port in virtual machine (as example 8080) with haproxy, but it work only when i bind 80 to 80, how? i dont have app at this port.
my docker-compose

```
  version: "3"
    services:
      node:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: dockerfile
        user: "node"
        networks:
          - back-tier
        working_dir: /home/node/app
        environment:
          - NODE_ENV=production
        volumes:
          - ./:/home/node/app
      lb:
        image: 'dockercloud/haproxy:latest'
        links:
          - node
        volumes:
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        ports:
          - 80:80 #(node work on port 8080)
        networks:
          - front-tier
          - back-tier
        depends_on:
          - node
        environment:
          - BALANCE=leastconn
    networks:
      front-tier:
        driver: bridge
      back-tier:
        driver: bridge
        internal: true
```

my dockerfile for web app

```
FROM node:12.13.1-alpine3.10
WORKDIR /home/node/app
RUN npm install -g nodemon
#RUN npm install

CMD [ "nodemon", "index.js" ]
```

thank

Comment: What's your specific problem?  Your Dockerfile is missing some key parts (like `COPY` the `index.js` file in that it's running) and won't produce a runnable image.

Comment: dockerfile is in the same directory as index.js. I do not need to copy him.
Issue with port binding. I dont understand it, and i don't found info in manuals to docker or haproxy.
as example, i don't expose 8080, but my app is work and i can see it, how it possible?
and how i have to make port binding in haproxy? On port 80 in docker work nothing, but regardless of this, the application is available from browser